# Especificación de identidad en relación uno-uno con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Se me presentó una duda con respecto a la definición del `Identity` para dos entidades que tienen relación uno a uno.

Actualmente tengo este código:

```
public class Propiedad
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Caracteristica_Propiedad Caracteristica_Propiedad { get; set; }
}

public class Caracteristica_Propiedad
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Propiedad Propiedad { get; set; }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si puedo aplicar en la entidad `Caracteristica_Propiedad` el `Identity`.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Y además, quisiera saber si es una buena práctica ya que el `id` de las entidades deben ser iguales o ¿se puede utilizar otra estrategia?

Answer (score 1):

En `Caracteristica_Propiedad` no puedes aplicar el identity porque esta deberia usar el id generado por la tabla `Propiedad`

Si la tabla de caracteristicas generara su id la secuencia podria variar respecto a la tabla Propiedad, por lo tanto no podrias unirias la asincronia entre los nro de id generados.

[Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

veras en el articulo como hace uso del [ForeignKey]

```
public class Propiedad
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Caracteristica_Propiedad Caracteristica_Propiedad { get; set; }
}

public class Caracteristica_Propiedad
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Propiedad")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Propiedad Propiedad { get; set; }
}
```

entiendo que usas DataAnnotations en lugar de Fluent API

Comment: Leandro, era lo que yo pensaba. Una consulta, se puede aplicar por medio de EF o por medio de SQL que el campo Id de Caracteristica_Propiedad sea de tipo readonly como te lo genera el motor de SQL cuando esta seteado el identity? Me llego un requerimiento en el cual no se debe poder modificar de forma manual a traves del SQL managment studio. Con esto de que no puedo aplicar el identity no sabría como resolverlo.

Comment: si la relacion es uno a uno no vas a poder cambiar el id de la entidad Caracteristicas, ya que por la relacion de integridad no vas a poder asignar uno que no exista en la tabla de Propiedad y tampoco vas a poder asignar uno ya existente porque se duplicaria con otro que ya lo tiene asignado. Intenta realizar la prueba y veras que desde la db no vas a poder reasignar el id