# Relacion one-to-one en Entity Framework mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tengo dos entidades, Servicio y Contrato, su relación debe ser de uno a uno.
el requerimiento es simple. como puedo lograr esto por medio de data annotations o fluent api.

el siguiente es el código que tengo (Entidad Servicio)

```
[ForeignKey("Contrato"]    
public string NumeroLinea { get; set; }

public virtual Contrato Contrato { get; set; }
```

(Entidad Contrato)

```
public virtual Servicio Servicio {get; set; }
```

--> Cuando hago la migración, me genera múltiples errores.

> el siguiente es el error:
>   **Servicio_Contrato_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Servicio_Contrato_Source' in relationship 'Servicio_Contrato'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.**

Comment: y sus avances ?

Comment: @Rastalovely que pena, no se porque no lo había subido.

Comment: @Rastalovely tengo entendido que puede hacerse más fácil por data Anonotation que por fluent api, pero cualquier solución sería importante

Comment: y si colocas los errores?

Comment: @fredyfx ya, puedes ver que me aparece cuando trato de hacer la migración.

Comment: @fredyfx por favor, si puedes ayudarme estría muy agradecido, llevo vario tiempo con este error.

Comment: tienes muy pocos detalles en tu pregunta, sin embargo, dale una lectura a este post: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations y a este otro http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/27/entity-framework-with-many-to-many-one-to-many-and-one-to-one-relationships/ :D

Comment: @Drz  Aca hay una pregunta paracida http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23065/especificacion-de-identidad-en-relaci%C3%B3n-uno-uno-con-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

Aquí ambas entidades necesitan tener Id (Una llave primaria) para poder crear las llaves foraneas, es decir:

Entidad de Contrato

```
public Contrato
{
  [Key]
  public long Id {get; set;}

  //... Otras propiedades aquí ...

  public long IdServicio {get; set;}      

  [ForeignKey("IdServicio")]
  public virtual Servicio Servicio {get; set;}
}
```

Entidad de Servicio

```
public Servicio
{
  [Key]
  public long Id {get; set;}

  //... Otras propiedades aquí ...

  public long IdContrato {get; set;}      

  [ForeignKey("IdContrato")]
  public virtual Contrato Contrato {get; set;}
}
```

Saludos